# Why pandas is throwing error: 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to create a new column base on the existing 2 columns from another dataframe like this:

```
count_percent['file_name_%'] = counts['file_name']*100/counts['upload']
```

I got this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Here is more details on how I create the new dataframe:

```
count_percent = counts[['created_year', 'quarter']]
count_percent['file_name_%'] = counts['file_name']*100/counts['upload']
```

Here is the sample of the counts dataframe

```
    created_year    quarter upload  file_name   
0   2015            1       22550   8.0 
1   2015            2       24350   13.0
2   2015            3       25736   7.0
```

Why I have the error and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data frames?  I am not getting the warning you are seeing.  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Also what is the version of pandas? pd.__version__

Comment: I am using pandas version '0.19.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ?

```
count_percent = counts[['created_year', 'quarter']]
count_percent.insert(0,'file_name_%',counts.loc[:,'file_name']*100/counts.loc[:,'upload'])
```

The explaination in the link is precise and the warning justified. Please consider my solution (inserting a pd.series) as an explicit workaround for this simple case.